# Server connection example head first c (Segmentation fault (`core' generado))

Tags: c

I'd really appreciate if any could help me fixing this:

I'm running an example from head first c page 473. Bellow is my code. I'm using telnet to run it, but I get this error: Segmentation fault (`core' generado). Any advice? thanks.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char * advice[] = {
    "Take smaller bites\r\n,"
    "One word: inappropiate\r\n"
    };

    int listener_d = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listener_d == -1)
    {
        printf("Can't open socket");
    }
    else
    {   
            struct sockaddr_in name;
            name.sin_family = PF_INET;
            name.sin_port = (in_port_t)htons(30000);
            name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
            int c = bind(listener_d, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(name));

            if (c == -1)
            {
                printf("Can't bind to socket");
            }
            else
            {
                if((listen(listener_d,10)) == -1)
                {
                    printf("Can't Listen"); 
                }
                else
                {
                    puts("Waiting for connection");

                    while(1)
                    {
                        struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
                        unsigned int address_size = sizeof(client_addr);
                        int connect_d = accept(listener_d, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &address_size);
                        if (connect_d == -1)
                        {
                            printf("Can't open secondary socket");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            char *msg = advice[rand() % 2];
                            if ((send(connect_d, msg, strlen(msg), 0))== -1);
                                printf("Can't send the message");
                            close(connect_d);
                        }                   
                    }       
                }                   
            }
        }           
    return 0;
}
```

Screen shot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Surely you've used a debugger or added prints to identify which line is crashing?

Comment: @John3136   "I have a dream......."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, compile your program in debug mode via:

```
gcc infile.c -O0 -ggdb
```

Now, launch your program with GDB:

```
gdb ./a.out
RUN
```

From the debug logs, we see that it looks there are issues accessing the `advice` string:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/owner/tmp/a.out 
Waiting for connection

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_sse2_bsf () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen-sse2-bsf.S:50
50  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen-sse2-bsf.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt full
#0  __strlen_sse2_bsf () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strlen-sse2-bsf.S:50
No locals.
#1  0x080487d6 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff4d4) at test.c:51
        msg = 0x10 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x10>
        client_addr = {ss_family = 2, __ss_align = 16777343, 
          __ss_padding = '\000' <repeats 12 times>, "t\364\377\277\350\363\377\277\340\363\377\277P\203\004\b8\371\377\267\000\000\000\000\277\000\000\000F\302\351\267\377\377\377\377\016\364\377\277\370;\341\267s\242\343\267\000\000\000\000N0\264,\001\000\000\000a\204\004\b\253\366\377\277/\000\000\000\000\240\004\b\202\210\004\b\001\000\000\000\324\364\377\277\334\364\377\277-\244\343\267\304\023\373\267\000\360\377\267;\210\004\b"}
        address_size = 16
        connect_d = 4
        name = {sin_family = 2, sin_port = 12405, sin_addr = {s_addr = 0}, sin_zero = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}
        c = 0
        advice = {0x80488c0 "Take smaller bites\r\n,One word: inappropiate\r\n"}
        listener_d = 3
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 14423] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

Upon closer inspection, you have typos and a misplaced comma:

Your declaration and definition of `advice` should be like so:

```
char **advice = (char*[]) {
    "Take smaller bites\r\n",
    "One word: inappropiate\r\n"
};
```

You accidentally put the comma inside of the `"Take smaller bites"` string, so your array of strings only had a single string element, but your modulo arithmetic `%2` meant that sometimes you would be trying to access a non-existent (ie: out of bounds) array element.

The reason for this is because C treats whitespace-separate string literals as a single string, so:

```
"This is a string"  "And this too"
```

Becomes concatenated to a single string, `This is a stringAnd this too`.

Comment: Sorry I'm answering so late, however, I saw your answer back then and fix my mistake. Thanks buddy